# Find word with commas

Tags: string, powershell

i need the following query in powershell.

If UserName contains a comma (givenName, surname) do this, if Username does not contain a comma (givenName surname) do that.

Many thanks for any help

Comment: Where are you getting the username from?

Comment: Hi Mathias,
`Get-ADUser $user -Properties memberof` -> Name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest possible regular expression with which you could assert whether a string contains a `,` would simply be `,`:

```
$user = Get-ADUser "<DN or sAMAccountName goes here>"
if($user.Name -match ','){
  # a comma was found in the Name attribute value
}
else {
  # no comma was found in the Name attribute value
}
```